Scratch Orgs with Account Engagement (Pardot) package basic setup, advice needed
I'm looking to setup Scratch Orgs on the project that is using Pardot.
But currently struggling with setup.
I used Prod org shape as a baseline and then tried to install Account Engagement Managed Package, but in the process get installation errors.
1.  Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class pi.PardotBusinessUnitQueryActionV2 : Type is not visible: ConnectApi.PardotBusinessUnitContext
PardotAPIWrapperTest: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class pi.PardotBusinessUnitQueryActionV2 : Type is not visible: ConnectApi.PardotBusinessUnitContext

2.  Type is not visible: ConnectApi.PardotBusinessUnitContext
PardotBusinessUnitQueryActionV2: Type is not visible: ConnectApi.PardotBusinessUnitContext

3. (Account_Engagement_Bulk_Asset_Copy_Flow-5) Get_My_Business_Units (Action) - We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified.
Account_Engagement_Bulk_Asset_Copy_Flow-5: Get_My_Business_Units (Action) - We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified.

4. (Account_Engagement_Sandbox_Production_Bulk_Asset_Copy_Flow-4) Get_Production_Business_Units (Action) - We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified.
Account_Engagement_Sandbox_Production_Bulk_Asset_Copy_Flow-4: Get_Production_Business_Units (Action) - We can't find an action with the name and action type that you specified.

Creating a ticket for the error above to see if support knows anything about it.
I also found that there were some discussion about enabling Pardot from org features, but I couldn't make it work at all.
https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/333
Does someone have a working Scratch Org setup with Pardot and maybe can give a tip on how to do it properly?
UPDATE:
Summary from GitHub, an example of working :
{
"orgName": "Test company",
"edition": "Developer",
"features": [
"Pardot",
],
"settings": {
"pardotSettings": {
"enablePardotEnabled": true,
"enablePardotAppV1Enabled": true,
"enableB2bmaAppEnabled": false,
"enableProspectActivityDataset": false
}
}
}
UPDATE 2:
after playing with this for 2 days, I'd say it's not worth it.
Scratch orgs randomly fail on creation with 9999 error code with no additional details.
Salesforce Support also won't help since it's an undocumented feature.

I also had this ConnectApi error when I was installing Pardot in a scratch org. I was able to successfully install the Pardot package after I enabled the  B2BCommerce feature.
I also put the undocumented Pardot feature in my scratch org definition file, but I don't think that's what did it.

what was the undocumented Pardot feature?

It was in a reply to the issue you linked to on github in your question i.e. adding Pardot to the features array.

thank you. I think it didn't work for me, but I'll give it a try

thank you, after much delay I tried and this time it worked. Thanks
